# Link Divblock with dynamic link

Tags: javascript, html

i'd like to link a divblock with the current position within the for-loop

Problem: all DivBlock get the link with the last position of the loop

my code is like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= kundenAnzahl; i++) {
    var block = document.createElement("div");
    block.id = i.toString();


document.getElementById(i.toString()).addEventListener('click', function() {
        location.href = 'server.html?kunde='+i
    }, true);
```

Comment: I'd try to use `let i = 1` instead of `var i = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

change *var* to *let* because -> https://wesbos.com/for-of-es6/

and you can assign event listeners directly to new created div element, look this code

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var block = document.createElement('div');

    block.addEventListener('click', function() {
        location.href = 'server.html?kunde='+i;
    }, true);

    document.body.append(block);
}
```